# Series involving a Logarithm

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, closed-form, gamma-function

Consider the series
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{n}{a} \ln\left(1 + \frac{a}{n}\right) - 1 + \frac{a}{2n} \right].
\end{align}
Is there a closed form solution to this series and what is the value when $a=1, 2$ ?

Comment: $$S(1)=1+\frac\gamma2-\ln\sqrt{2\pi}~,\qquad\qquad S\bigg(\frac12\bigg)=1+\frac\gamma4-\frac5{12}\ln2-3\ln\big(\text{Glaisher}\big)$$

Comment: $$S(a)=\ln(a!)+\frac{1+a(\gamma+1)}2-\ln\sqrt{2\pi}-\frac{\zeta(-1)+\zeta^{(1,0)}(-1,a+1)+\ln\big(\text{Glaisher}\big)}a$$

Comment: What still remains is a method to evaluate the series and then demonstrate the values listed.

Answer (score 1):

For small $|a|$, $\ln(1 + a/n) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j-1} (a/n)^j/j$, so your series is

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{j=2}^\infty (-1)^{j} \dfrac{a^{j}}{(j+1)\; n^{j}}
= \sum_{j=2}^\infty \dfrac{(-a)^{j}}{j+1} \zeta(j)$$

I don't think this has a closed form.

Comment: It does, to the extent to which $\zeta^{(1,0)}(-1,a+1)$ has one as well: see my comment on the main post.